# How to click on open link in new tab to open the link in new tab that appears in main tab using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate google search with the code:

```
driver.get("google.com");
driver.findelement(By.id("lst-ib").sendkeys("search");
driver.findelement(By.classname(lsb)).click;
```

I am trying to open the suggestion links after entering `search` keyword in search box in new tab i.e 5 links in 5 new tabs in same window
code for that I wrote:

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.COMMAND).send_keys("t").key_up(Keys.COMMAND)‌​‌​.perform();
```

but its not opening the links in new tabs

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the open-in-new-tab thing by holding the Ctrl key while clicking:

```
new Actions(driver)
    .KeyDown(Keys.Control)
    .Click(element)
    .KeyUp(Keys.Control)
    .Perform(); // C# syntax, as I'm not familiar with Java...
```

Comment: Hi can you please suggest how can i focus to that link and then will back to previous tab

Answer (score 0):

This is how I gained focus and right clicked and opened same on new tab after using below mentioned code:

```
link=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'After Life (TV Series 2019– ) - IMDb')]")
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.context_click(link).perform()
ac=driver.switch_to.active_element
actionChains.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(ac).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```